# What is the difference between using brackets and straight lines when solving a matrix?

Tags: matrices

When solving Matrices, why do some sets have lines like this : ||
And others have brackets, like this: [ ]

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol [A] indicates the matrix A whereas the symbol |A| indicates the determinant of A.